# why some fields hidden from node?

Tags: 7, entities

well I have a content type in which I needed about 6 taxonomy fields..

it was working at first but suddenly it stopped showing taxonomy fields in node display page.

I used Field Permissions and Field Group modules and I show the fields in content type's display management. but nothing changed!

although I can use views to get and show the data but it may be an error in my drupal core or something.

Update: I disabled field group and field permissions.. every thing works fine now! but cause I need these modules I should continue trying!

Comment: Are you using a template file?

Comment: just seven (default admin theme)

Answer (score 0):

I it been a **long time that** you created that content type ?

It is on a **production** website already ?

Are you working on a **fresh** Drupal 7 installation ?

You could **delete** and **recreate** that content type if there is no serious impact on your site or your data.

If you do that, then your can check if the situation happens again. Sometimes there are particular manipulations while working that are responsible for those situations (and you can find out if you did something in a certain way the first time).

**But remember** : to me this operation depends on the 3 questions that I've asked on top of this text.

Does it help a bit ?

Comment: tnx.. the content type is working about 6 months,, it is pre-production but some data entry is done, I made the content type on a fresh drupal bat its not that fresh today! not mentioning the data entry the content type has more than 80 fields! it is not easy to delete and remake that!

Comment: @MahdiIranmanesh 80 fields for 1 content type sounds overkill. I bet it takes a while for your node to load. You're probably approaching your architecture the wrong way.

Comment: @noSssweat yeah the content type is a killer! but I had no choice but using entity reference (which I used to connect other parts to the type!) my case is not a simple website it works as a project manager system!

Comment: @MahdiIranmanesh is also wright. I have made a website last that had a 180 fields' content type. It gave me a lot of headaches. Until I decided to divide that form into 7 parts. That content type was supposed to handle several categories of information. Those categories also had sub categories. So when I decided create 7 content type (based on the same structure) instead of one, things are working well since then. Few fields per content type. A lot of work to administrate, but a better organization, and it is easier to find-out malfunctions and bugs for monthly maintenance.